# Wamp allow from ip access

Tags: wamp, httpd.conf

I have multiple virtual machines with manual IP adresses:

- 190.0.0.2
- 190.0.0.3
- 190.0.0.4
- 191.0.0.2
- 191.0.0.3

190.0.0.2 has a WAMP installation. In the httpd.conf I gave access to other 190's machines and it works well.

`<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
Allow from localhost
Allow from 190.0.0.3
Allow from 190.0.0.4
</Directory>`

Unfortunately when I try to add the 191's machines using the same method:

`Allow from 191.0.0.2
Allow from 191.0.0.3`

the access is forbidden: "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer and or Apache are you using?

Comment: WAMPServer 2.4. It is the latest for Win XP.